# fastify set reply headers for all routes

Tags: fastify

For every route I have to type the same headers as shown below. Is there a way to set these headers globally so that they are used by default for every route and can be overridden on a per-route basis?

```js
fastify.post("/api/users", async (request, reply) => {
    try {
        reply
            .code(200)
             header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .send();
    } catch (error) {
        reply
            .code(400)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .send();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set some headers before use `send()`

```
fastify.addHook('preHandler', (req, repy, done) => {
  reply.header("key", "value")
  done()
})

fastify.post("api/users", async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    reply.code(200).send()
  } catch (err) {
    reply.code(400).send()
  }
})
```

But I saw you want to use CORS, why not use [fastify-cors](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors) ?

Comment: onSend seems to be more appropriate

Comment: The reason not to use `fastify-cors` is that it's an entire package to learn and add to project, all to do something that should be easy and would be more valuable to learn in another way.  I have an answer elsewhere that shows how to work with headers for cors:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74131067/4808079